# Autocomplete <ol> and <li> with data from MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, loops

MySQL returns to me this data:

<s>[Datas from MySQL step 2](http://arthur.ochin.free.fr/data_step1.JPG)</s>

<s>[Datas from MySQL step 3](http://arthur.ochin.free.fr/data_step2.JPG)</s>

This is my HTML code :

```
<div id="chapitrage" >
   <ol id="liste_chapitre">
   </ol>
</div>
```

I need to create in my `<ol id="liste_chapitre">` a `<ul>` for each "Chapitres" and in this each `<ul>` make `<li>` for each "Video" which are in each "Chapitres".

Something like that :

```
<div id="chapitrage" >
            <ol id="liste_chapitre">
                <ul id="chap0">
                    <div>name_Chapitre[index0]</div>
                        <li>name_Video[index0]</li>
                        <li>name_Video[index1]</li>
                        <li>name_Video[index2]</li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="chap1">
                    <div>name_Chapitre[index1]</div>
                    <li>name_Video[index0]</li>
                    <li>name_Video[index1]</li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="chap2">
                    <div>name_Chapitre[index2]</div>
                        <li>name_Video[index0]</li>
                        <li>name_Video[index1]</li>
                        <li>name_Video[index2]</li>
                </ul>
            </ol>
```

I tried with that but it's awful...

```
$.each(e.valeur_tableau_infos_tutoriel.Chapitres, function (idx, chapitre) {
        $("#chapitrage #liste_chapitre").append("<ul>"+e.valeur_tableau_infos_tutoriel.Chapitres.titre_chapitre+"</ul>");
                $.each(chapitre.Videos, function (idx, video) {
                    $("#liste_chapitre ul").append("<li></li>");
                    $("#liste_chapitre ul li").append(e.valeur_tableau_infos_tutoriel.Chapitres.Videos);
                });
    });
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You better go through https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

```
$.each(e.valeur_tableau_infos_tutoriel.Chapitres, function (idx, chapitre) {
        $(".liste_chapitre").append("<li id='"+idx+"'><div>"+e.valeur_tableau_infos_tutoriel.Chapitres[idx].titre_chapitre+"</div><ul></ul></li>");
            $.each(chapitre.Videos, function (index, video) {

                $(".liste_chapitre li#"+idx+" ul").append(
                    "<li>"+
                        "<div class='titre'><span class='icon icon-play4'></span>"+video.titre+"</div>"+
                        "<div class='duree'>"+nbMinutes+"min "+nbSecondes+"s</div>"+
                        "<div class='niveau'><span class='icon icon-"+niv+"'></span></div>"+
                        "<div class='prix'>"+video.prix+"</div>"+
                    "</li>"
                );
        });
    });
```